# Generating a PHP list with "and"

Tags: php

What's an efficient way to format an array in PHP as a list with commas and the word "and" before the last element?

```
$array = Array('a','b','c','d');
```

I want to produce the string "a, b, c, and d"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would modify the `$array` in place to add the `"and"`, and then join the parts with commas for output:

```
array_push($array, " and " . array_pop($array));
print join(", ", $array);
```

But you might as well just use [`array_pop`](http://php.net/array_pop) to separate the last entry, join the rest, and then append the "and" and last entry.

Comment: Slight caution: if you use this as a generic function and pass it a one-element array this will return 'and a'. Two elements will return 'a, and b.' This may or may not be what you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that should do it:

```
$array[ sizeof($array) - 1 ] = 'and ' . $array[ sizeof($array) - 1 ];
$list = implode(', ', $array);
```

Comment: In some reason I thought that `and` shouldn't be preceded by comma, like `a, b and c`

Comment: @zerkms a comma is optional here

Comment: @sanmai: yep, but being specified it looks unnatural imho

Comment: @zerkms By the way, look up Oxford comma: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list

Comment: @Stanislav Shabalin: yeah, I've read that discussion long ago, but according to my russian origins (and respective grammar) - it looks unnatural for me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could do it, here is one:

```
<?

$array = Array('a','b','c','d');

$string=implode(',',$array);

$nstring=substr_replace($string,' and ', -1, 0);

echo $nstring;
```

Comment: You forgot spaces after commas ;-)

Comment: This only works if the last element is only one character long!

Comment: Ah, well I was going exactly off the specs you gave, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = Array('a','b','c','d');

$array[count($array)-1] = 'and '.$array[count($array)-1];
echo implode($array, ', ');

?>
```

http://codepad.org/7oeni6xv

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function arrayEnum($array)
{
    $string = '';
    for (i = 0, $l = count($array); i < $l; ++i)
    {
        $string .= $array[$i];
        if (i != ($l -1)) $string .= ', ';
        if (i == ($l -2)) $string .= 'and '
    }
}

$array = Array('a','b','c','d');
echo $array; // a, b, c, and d
$array = Array('one','two','three','four');
echo $array; // one, two, three and four
```

That function will work with any length of data.